# T-SQL query to insert missing values in a table based on 2 columns combination criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL Server 2016 table that holds all possible combination of 3 colors and 3 shapes:

```
Color       Shape
---------------------
red         square
red         circle
red         octagon
yellow      square
yellow      circle
yellow      octagon
green       square
green       circle
green       octagon
```

I have the following data table that contains "objects" as follows (there are no duplicates):

```
Object ID              Shape            Color
------------------------------------------------
object1                square           green
object1                square           red
object1                octagon          yellow
object1                circle           green
object2                circle           red
object2                square           yellow
object3                square           red
object3                circle           red
object3                square           yellow
object3                square           yellow
object3                octagon          green
object4                circle           red
etc......
etc......
object100
```

As you can see there are some "gaps" in terms of shape+color combination for each object.

What I would like to achieve is to insert any missing combination of shape+color for each [object] record. Desired output for object1 and object2 would be for example:

```
     Object ID            Color       Shape
     -------------------------------------------
     object1              red         square
     object1              red         circle
     object1              red         octagon
     object1              yellow      square
     object1              yellow      circle
     object1              yellow      octagon
     object1              green       square
     object1              green       circle
     object1              green       octagon 
     object2              red         square
     object2              red         circle
     object2              red         octagon
     object2              yellow      square
     object2              yellow      circle
     object2              yellow      octagon
     object2              green       square
     object2              green       circle
     object2              green       octagon
     etc......
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this to insert your missing values in this way based on the output you have mentioned as well.

```
create table color (colors varchar(10), Shape varchar(10))
insert into color values  
('red'       ,  'square'  )
,('red'       ,  'circle'  )
,('red'       ,  'octagon' )
,('yellow'    ,  'square'  )
,('yellow'    ,  'circle'  )
,('yellow'    ,  'octagon' )
,('green'     ,  'square'  )
,('green'     ,  'circle'  )
,('green'     ,  'octagon' ) 


create table objectsnew (objectID varchar(20), Shape varchar(10),colors varchar(10))
insert into objectsnew values
 ('object1' ,  'square'  ,  'green'  )
,('object1' ,  'square'  ,  'red'    )
,('object1' ,  'octagon' ,  'yellow' )
,('object1' ,  'circle'  ,  'green'  )
,('object2' ,  'circle'  ,  'red'    )
,('object2' ,  'square'  ,  'yellow' )
,('object3' ,  'square'  ,  'red'    )
,('object3' ,  'circle'  ,  'red'    )
,('object3' ,  'square'  ,  'yellow' )
,('object3' ,  'square'  ,  'yellow' )
,('object3' ,  'octagon' ,  'green'  )
,('object4' ,  'circle'  ,  'red'    )
```

--Use this to make sure that you are inserting only unique combination for each object ID.

```
insert into objectsnew (objectID, Shape, colors) 

select o.objectID,  c.Shape, o.colors  from color c 
join objectsnew o on c.colors = o.colors 
except 
select objectID, Shape, colors   from objectsnew 
order by o.objectID  , o.colors
```

Output

```
 objectID   Shape   colors
 object1    octagon green
 object1    circle  green
 object1    square  green
 object1    square  red
 object1    octagon red
 object1    circle  red
 object1    circle  yellow
 object1    square  yellow
 object1    octagon yellow
 Etc.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `CROSS JOIN` and `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT t2.[Object ID],t1.*
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Color,Shape FROM T1) t1
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT [Object ID] FROM T2) t2
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31424b0dc748ccf6bac255de80320c17)

Answer (score 0):

The following generates the rows to be inserted:

```
select cs.color, cs.shape, oi.objectID
from colorshape cs cross join
     (select distinct o.objectID from objects o) oi
where not exists (select 1
                  from objects o
                  where o.color = cs.color and
                        o.shape = cs.shape and
                        o.objectId = oi.objectId
                 );
```

You can add an `insert` before this to insert these into the table.